# pythonでデータの点群のみから極座標でのplot_surfaceを行いたい

Tags: python, matplotlib

python3.5を使っています。例えばmatplotlibのplot_surface()を使って球を描写するには次のようなコードを書けば描写できます。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

r=1
p = np.linspace(0, 2* np.pi, 10)
t = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 10)
p, t = np.meshgrid(p, t)

x = r* np.sin(t)* np.cos(p)
y = r* np.sin(t)* np.sin(p)
z = r* np.cos(t)

# plotting :-
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot( 111 , projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim(-1,1)
ax.set_ylim(-1,1)
ax.set_zlim(-1,1)
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, linewidth = .5,edgecolor='k',cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, antialiased=True)
ax.scatter(x,y,z)
```

上のコードを実行することで次のような球を描写することが出来ます。
[image: 画像]

ここで、極座標的なデータの点群のみが存在する際に同様にplot_surface()の様に3次元の表面を補完したいです。例えば次のようなx_list、y_list、z_listの点群がデータとして存在したとします。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d



r=1
p = np.linspace(0, 2* np.pi, 10)
t = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 10)
p, t = np.meshgrid(p, t)

x = r* np.sin(t)* np.cos(p)
y = r* np.sin(t)* np.sin(p)
z = r* np.cos(t)


x_list=[]
y_list=[]
z_list=[]
for i in range(0,len(p)):
    for j in range(0,len(t)):
        x_list.append(x[i][j])
        y_list.append(y[i][j])
        z_list.append(z[i][j])


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot( 111 , projection='3d')

ax.scatter(x_list,y_list,z_list)
```

[image: 画像2]

ここで、x_list,y_list,z_listの情報のみがデータとして存在している状態で、その点群を最初の例の様に、表面を補完したような図に直すことは出来るのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問の意図を読み誤っているのかもしれませんが、`x_list` などを `numpy.reshape` で元の構造に戻せば良いかと思います。

```py
            :
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(
  np.array(x_list).reshape(len(p), len(t)),
  np.array(y_list).reshape(len(p), len(t)),
  np.array(z_list).reshape(len(p), len(t)),
  linewidth = .5, edgecolor='k',
  cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, antialiased=True)

ax.scatter(x_list,y_list,z_list)
            :
```

Answer (score 0):

点群が構成する面に凹なところが無いのであれば、各点から最も近い点に辺を張り、辺で接続された点群から面を構成することで、立体の表面を構成することは可能だと思います。

Comment: 質問では球で考えていますが、最終的には凹凸がある場合を想定しています。

Comment: リンゴの果柄がついていた部分のように深く凹んだところがあると、最も近い点どうしを辺で結ぶというアルゴリズムだけでは難しいと思います。
球体に近いという仮定ができるのであれば、球(外接球か内接球)の中心に近い点を除外して、凹みを取り除くというようなヒューリスティックがあったような気がします。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。デフォルトで極座標を表面補間してくれる機能は無いんですね。とりあえず近いことは出来ないのか、もう少し頑張ってみます。